# C reading text file and put content into structure

Tags: c, ansi-c

So, i have a text file, with content like this, seperated by space:

> int int int char int char int char,example: 1 10 1 A 2 B 3 C

that means the delivery id is 1,the day of the month is 10, I have 1 A that worth 10$/piece, so thats 10$total, I have 2 B that worth 20$/piece so that 2*20$, and so on, maximum char is F, so overally 6 item. I want to put it on a data structure, but the problem is that not every char is mentioned in every line, if there is 0 from a char than its not on the line in any way

> 1A 2C

Example above, 0 B so there is no B in any form in that line.
What method should I use, to process the file, and avoid memory garbage?I tried with fscanf but I dont know how many chars are going to be in the line. The file can be up to 1000 lines, I searched around and found out that

```
while(!feof(file))
```

is not a reliable way to read the file until the last line, I run a For cycle to read 1000 line and tried to seperate the garbage but it was really uneffective.
my structure looks like:

```
    typedef struct
{
    int id;
    int day;
    int numberofitems[6];

}asd;
```

numberofitems is 0 for A, 1 for B, 2 for C ... 5 for F,

overally the txt file can look like this but with a lot of more line:

3 12 4 B 3 C 9 F 5 D
4 12 6 B 8 C 1 D 9 F 3 A
5 12 6 C 7 A 3 B

How should I process this text file?

Comment: The example `1 10 1 A 2 B 3 C` is not of the form "int char int char int char", unless you are considering the space to be a char, in which case it is of the form "int char int char int char char char int ...`

Comment: In the second line of your example, there are 2 F values. Can this happen in reality or is this a typo ? Should we add the F ? I would read the file line by line, and use `strsep` to split the line at spaces. I would then use `atoi` to decode the numeric values and compare with 'A', 'B',... to recognize the letters in a switch.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, every char only could happen once in a line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of scanf, but you might try something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct asd {
        int id;
        int day;
        int numberofitems[6];
};

void die(const char *fmt, ... )  __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)));

int
main(void)
{
        char buf[1024];
        int line = 0;
        while( fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL ) {
                int count;
                int len;
                char item;
                struct asd a = {0};
                char *p = buf;
                line += 1;
                if(sscanf(p, "%d %d%n", &a.id, &a.day, &len) != 2) {
                        die("Invalid input at line %d\n", line);
                }
                p += len;
                for(int i=0; i < 6 && sscanf(p, "%d %c%n", &count, &item, &len) == 2; i++ ) {
                        if( ! strchr("ABCDEF", item) ) {
                                die("Invalid input at line %d\n", line);
                        }
                        a.numberofitems[item - 'A'] = count;
                        p += len;
                }
                printf("id = %d, day = %d\n", a.id, a.day);
                for(int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
                        printf("\tnum[%c] = %d\n", 'A' + i, a.numberofitems[i]);
                }
        }
}

void
die(const char *fmt, ... )
{
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, fmt);
        vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
        va_end(ap);
        exit(1);
}
```